# Bash associative arrays be initialized in a (...) list?

Tags: bash, shell, initialization, associative-array

Can bash associative arrays be initialized in a (...) list similarly to non associative arrays? Format?

Updating to give an answer using the comments.

Yes, the format depends on the version of bash. For GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1), it is
declare -A AR=([key1]=value1 [key2]=value2)

The available default format can be found out with
declare -p AR

Comment: Yes, they can. The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) explains how to do it.

Comment: Barmar, thank you very much, especially for the Reference Manual link!

Comment: Barmar, However when I try #declare -A AR=(k1 v1 k2 v2), I get errors like:
bash: AR: k1: must use subscript when assigning associative array ...   Subscripted keys form like AR=([k1]=v1 ...) works. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's right. If it's an associative array, you have to specify thekeys.

Comment: What do you expect the keys to be if you just write `(k1 v2 k2 v2)`? That's just an array with 4 values.

Comment: Yes, that could be confusing. But the manual  you kindly sent me specifies explicitly otherwise:  "When assigning to an associative array, the words in a compound assignment may be either assignment statements, for which the subscript is required, or a list of words that is interpreted as a sequence of alternating keys and values: name=(key1 value1 key2 value2 … ). These are treated identically to name=( [key1]=value1 [key2]=value2 … ). "

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? Apparently that feature is new in 5.1.

Comment: That expains it. Mine:GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  For example:

```
declare -A assoc=(["1 2"]="3 4" ["a b"]="c d" )
```

If you've got a populated associated array (`assoc` say) and you want to see how it could be initialized run

```
declare -p assoc
```

That's how I got the initialization command above.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an associative array over multiple lines, for readability. Note that you do not need to quote the array keys:

```bash
declare -A person=(
    [name]='John'
    [city]='New York'
    [job]='Software Engineer'
)

echo "${person['name']}"  # John
echo "${person['city']}"  # New York
echo "${person['job']}"   # Software Engineer
```